# Customizing the installation Wizard in .net

Tags: .net, installation

My application involves lot of questions to be asked to the installer, the visual studio allows only a predefined set of controls for the installation wizard, Is there a way to add lot more controls to our Installation Wizard. can you help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

vdproj's are getting deprecated and are no longer supported. Your best bet (which will also address your concern here) is to migrate to Wix. It's a steep learning curve and some of the simplest things have become completely non-trivial, but sadly, the other two options I've pursued haven't worked out:

1. InstallShield LE - it freezes my computer and Visual Studio consistently and doesn't build randomly. Just plain doesn't work well.
2. NSIS - MSIs are a requirement these days for corporate network deployment.

That said, Wix is extremely powerful and customizable, so it does have its positives.

Answer (score 0):

I know this trick works for adding web controls to class library projects, but I'm not sure if it will work for you can do this for installation projects. It's definitely worth a shot though!

**First, back up your project.**

Open the project file in an editor, and replace the `projecttypeguids` setting with the following:

```
<projecttypeguids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</projecttypeguids>
```

Here's a link that explains it in more detail:
http://www.aaronblake.co.uk/blog/2009/09/28/how-to-add-web-user-controls-to-a-class-library-project/

You might want to check out this article too:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/01/15/extending-visual-studio-setup-project-part-1.aspx